# Is there analog of theano.tensor.switch in pytorch?

Tags: deep-learning, theano, pytorch

I'd like to force to zero all elements of a vector which are below a certain threshold. And I'd like to do it so that I can still propagate gradient through non-zero ones.

For example, in theano I could write:

`B = theano.tensor.switch(A < .1, 0, A)`

Is there a solution for that in pytorch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of pytorch 0.4+, you can do it easily with `torch.where`(see [doc](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/generated/torch.where.html),[Merged PR](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/pull/4298))

It is as easy as in Theano. See yourself with an example:

```py
import torch
from torch.autograd import Variable

x = Variable(torch.arange(0,4), requires_grad=True) # x     = [0 1 2 3]
zeros = Variable(torch.zeros(*x.shape))             # zeros = [0 0 0 0]

y = x**2                         # y = [0 1 4 9]
z = torch.where(y < 5, zeros, y) # z = [0 0 0 9]

# dz/dx = (dz/dy)(dy/dx) = (y < 5)(0) + (y ≥ 5)(2x) = 2x(x**2 ≥ 5) 
z.backward(torch.Tensor([1.0])) 
x.grad # (dz/dx) = [0 0 0 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I do not suppose that `switch` is implemented by default in PyTorch. But, you can define your own function in PyTorch by [extending the `torch.autograd.Function`](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/extending.html#extending-torch-autograd)

So, the switch function will look something like

```
class switchFunction(Function):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, flag, value, tensor):
        ctx.save_for_backward(flag)
        tensor[flag] = value
        return tensor

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):
        flag, = ctx.saved_variables
        grad_output[flag] = 0
        return grad_output
switch = switchFunction.apply
```

Now, you can simply call `switch` as `switch(A < 0.1, 0, A)`

### Edit

There is actually a function that does this. It is called [Threshold](http://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Threshold). You can use it like

```
import torch.nn as nn
m = nn.Threshold(0.1, 0)
B = m(A)
```